# Add Field To All ETW Events In EventSource

Tags: c#, etw, eventsource, etw-eventsource

Currently, my ETW events are defined like this:

```
public class MyEventSource: EventSource
{
    [Event(1, Level=Info)]
    public void WriteMyEvent(string Message)
    {
        WriteEvent(1, Message);
    }

    [Event(2, Level=Info)]
    public void WriteOtherEvent(string Details) 
    {
        WriteEvent(2, Details);
    }
}
```

I'd like to add a field to both of these events that callers do not need to pass in. It is a static string that is defined in app configuration. I've found that there is no way to add it to every `WriteEvent` call other than adding it to the parameters of the `[Event]` decorated function.

```
public class MyEventSource: EventSource
{
    public static readonly string MyDefault = "something";

    [Event(1, Level=Info)]
    public void WriteMyEvent(string Message, string Default = null)
    {
        // Ignore input "Default", use "MyDefault" instead
        WriteEvent(1, Message, MyDefault);
    }

    [Event(2, Level=Info)]
    public void WriteOtherEvent(string Details, string Default = null) 
    {
        // Ignore "Default"
        WriteEvent(2, Details, MyDefault);
    }
}
```

If I pipe these through a base `[NonEvent]` method, they garble the output. The above code block is the only way I've found of adding the field to every Event. There has to be a better way, but I have been unable as of yet to come up with the perfect Google search to find out how this is done.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Log a separate event to log the information

Comment: I want every event to log the name of the environment it is coming from

Comment: use ActivityID to group them and raise 1 event with the name of the environment so you see which Events have same ActivityID and from which environment they came.

Comment: That's a hack, and a searing headache to deal with 100+ microservices trying to correlate which logs came from my "prod" environment.

Comment: no, ActivityID was added just for your case

Comment: I shouldn't have to join query results just to see which environment the event came from. Furthermore, you're presenting a hack to solve my use-case when my root question still stands: how do you add a field to every event without adding it as a default parameter to the [Event] decorated method and ignoring the parameter?

Comment: it is not possible, because the manifest is generated based on the signature of the ETW event method. read [here more about Activities](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2015/09/14/exploring-eventsource-activity-correlation-and-causation-features/)